# Split EnterpriseLibrary Block configurations into multiple files

Tags: c#, configuration, enterprise-library, configuration-files

Is it possible to split the configuration for an **enterprise library block** into **multiple files**?

For example: I have three assemblies and one hosting project. I want to store the entlib v6 Exception Handling Application Block (EHAB) configuration for **each assembly** in a **separate config file** located in the particular assembly.

The hosting project references the three assemblies:

assembly_X

- ehabX.config

assembly_Y

- ehabY.config

assembly_Z

- ehabZ.config

Hosting project

- using ehabX.config
- using ehabY.config
- using ehabZ.config

I already tried the following:

**App.config in the hosting project:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="enterpriseLibrary.ConfigurationSource" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ConfigurationSourceSection, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common" requirePermission="true" />
  </configSections>

  <enterpriseLibrary.ConfigurationSource>
    <sources>
      <add name="ehabX" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.FileConfigurationSource, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common" filePath="ExceptionHandling\ehabX.config" />
      <add name="ehabY" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.FileConfigurationSource, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common" filePath="ExceptionHandling\ehabY.config" />
      <add name="ehabZ" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.FileConfigurationSource, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common" filePath="ExceptionHandling\ehabZ.config" />
    </sources>
    <redirectSections>
      <add sourceName="ehabX" name="exceptionHandling" />
      <add sourceName="ehabY" name="exceptionHandling" />
      <add sourceName="ehabZ" name="exceptionHandling" />
    </redirectSections>
  </enterpriseLibrary.ConfigurationSource>

</configuration>
```

**ehabX.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="exceptionHandling" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Configuration.ExceptionHandlingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling"/>
  </configSections>

  <exceptionHandling>
    <exceptionPolicies>
      <add name="Swallow NotImplementedException">
        <exceptionTypes>
          <add type="System.NotImplementedException, mscorlib" postHandlingAction="None" name="NotImplementedException"/>
        </exceptionTypes>
      </add>
    </exceptionPolicies>
  </exceptionHandling>

</configuration>
```

**ehabY.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="exceptionHandling" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Configuration.ExceptionHandlingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling"/>
  </configSections>

  <exceptionHandling>
    <exceptionPolicies>
      <add name="Swallow ArgumentException">
        <exceptionTypes>
          <add type="System.ArgumentException, mscorlib" postHandlingAction="None" name="NotImplementedException"/>
        </exceptionTypes>
      </add>
    </exceptionPolicies>
  </exceptionHandling>

</configuration>
```

The ehabZ.config is omitted.

Using the EHAB with the policy "Swallow NotImplementedException" works fine. But if I try to use the policy "Swallow ArgumentException" defnied in ehabY.config I get this error message:

*Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionHandlingException: The policy with name 'Swallow ArgumentException' cannot be found. Exception handling aborted.*

Any suggestions?

Comment: So you want to split the configuration into multiple files but at runtime merge them all back into one configuration set?

Comment: Yes Tuzo, that is what I want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is nothing out of the box that will let you merge multiple configuration sources into one configuration set.

I think you can probably do what you want but you will have to do some coding.  You'll need to read in the appropriate configuration sources and create a custom `IConfigurationSource` that will merge them all.  [Additive merge of different config sources?](https://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/253733) has an example of a MergeConfigurationSource that could help you.